# Get custom JWT Claim in each controller method injected

Tags: .net, api, jwt, .net-6.0

i have a .Net 6 API where I use JWT for auth.
My JWT token has a custom claim: "customId".

In every method of all my controllers, I want to get the customId.

I already know that I can get it using:
HttpContext (`var identity = HttpContext.User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;(...)`)

Or User (`User.Claims.SingleOrDefault(...)`)

But i want to get it *injected* directly on each authorized controller (or method), so I don't have to get it from `HttpContext` or `User` each time.

Does anyone know how I could do it?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a base controller class and define getting the claim implementation inside.

Something like:

```
public abstract class BaseController : ControllerBase
{
    protected string? GetCustomIdClaimValue()
    {
        
        return HttpContext?.User?.Claims?.FirstOrDefault(o => o.Type == "sometype")?.Value;
    }
}
```

Then you can declare every controller as a child of this class:

```
[Authorize]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ValuesController : BaseController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Get()
    {
        return Ok(GetCustomIdClaimValue());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Alexander, that's a great idea, not exactly what I was thinking, but better than having a helper class (which is what I had done now)